# How do I get the number of rendered pages from a CrystalReportsViewer?

Tags: wpf, crystal-reports

Using Crystal Reports 13 I'm able to get a rendered report to show; however, I'm unable to programmatically get the number of rendered pages from the control.

I've tried:

```
reportViewer.ViewerCore.GetLastPageNumber
reportViewer.ViewerCore.TotalPageNumber
report.AfterFormatPage += new FormatPageEventHandler(report_AfterFormatPage);
```

with no success.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the report is done rendering:

[How do I know Crystal Reports is done rendering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12959511/how-do-i-know-crystal-reports-is-done-rendering)

Just call:

```
reportViewer.ViewerCore.GetLastPageNumber();
```