# How do I know Crystal Reports is done rendering?

Tags: wpf, crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Reports 13 wpf control that I'm loading with a report and data from a dataset:

```
ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();
if (report != null)
{
  report.Load(ReportFileName);
  report.SetDataSource(DataSet);
  reportViewer.ViewerCore.ReportSource = report;
}
```

What event can I handle in order to know when the control is done rendering? The viewer exports:

```
public event PageMouseEventHandler ClickPage;
public event PageMouseEventHandler DoubleClickPage;
public event DrillEventHandler Drill;
public event DrillSubreportEventHandler DrillDownSubreport;
public event NavigateEventHandler Navigate;
public event RefreshEventHandler Refresh;
public event SearchEventHandler Search;
public event RoutedEventHandler SelectionChange;
public event RoutedEventHandler ViewChange;
public event ZoomEventHandler ViewZoom;
```

and ViewerCore only exports:

```
public event ExceptionEventHandler Error;
```

None of these seem plausible.  I've briefly played with the ReportClientDocument as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For posterity:

```
DependencyPropertyDescriptor p = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer.ViewerCore.TotalPageNumberProperty, typeof(SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer.ViewerCore));
p.AddValueChanged(reportViewer.ViewerCore, OnPageCountChanged);
```

Since the TotalPageNumber property is correctly updated after that page is rendered...

```
private void OnPageCountChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //do whats needed
}
```

You know when the control is done rendering.

Comment: Thank you; this didn't work for me in CR 13 (WinForms) but gave me the idea that led me to the solution I posted.

Comment: And what if ReportSource changes to smth with same amount of pages?

Answer (score 2):

In Crystal Reports 13 there's a PageChanged event that for some reason is not exposed in the UI (it has a `Browsable(false)` attribute). I needed to zoom the report and this event was the only non-hacky way I could do it: just do

```
viewer.PageChanged += Viewer_PageChanged;
```

in the form constructor and then add

```
private void Viewer_PageChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    viewer.Zoom(2);
}
```

to your private methods. (`viewer` is the `CrystalReportViewer` component on the form.)

Comment: Seems as if I have v13 but I don't have PageChanged event available (also not in CodeBehind). Any tips?

Comment: Okay just noticed that PageChanged is available in the WinForms version but not the WPF version

Comment: no its not even in windows forms version, I just checked, i dont know why its so complicated to locate this single event.